# Why do I need to duplicate the first parameter's label to make it show up in calls?

Tags: swift, parameters, swift2, naming-conventions, function-declaration

I have these two functions:

```
func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
            // here
func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() % (max - min) + min
}
```

Why I should write `min` two times in the second function in order to call it like this:

```
random(min: 1, max: 5);
```

Comment: Read the section *Function Parameter Names* in [Swift Language Guide: Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove second min from function. By the way when you call a function, skip the first variable name and just put the value. It's the swift syntax for calling a function

```
  func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
      return random() % (max - min) + min
  }

  func random() -> CGFloat {
      return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
  }

  random(1, max: 5)
```

Comment: This is bad design. Now, the method call is unintuitive. What does the `1` mean? It's unclear.

Comment: Please read the question, why did you down vote ? It's working as user asked

Comment: I believe this answer is not useful. The original poster wanted to call the function like this: `random(min: 1, max: 5);`, and this answer does not say how to do that. It also doesn't say why or when, or why its solution is better.

Comment: But this answer show alternative way to take the output.

Comment: An alternative, yes. However, that alternative is worse for the reasons I explain in my answer's "**Why?**" section.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Prior to Swift 3**, this was necessary. Declaring a function like this:

```
func foo(bar: Baz)
```

implicitly changed it to this:

```
func foo(_ bar: Baz)
```

which would make it be called like this:

```
foo(Baz())
```

so one would have to declare it like this:

```
func foo(bar bar: Baz)
```

in order to call it like this:

```
foo(bar: Baz())
```

**Since Swift 3**, this is no longer necessary. Now, declaring a function like this:

```
func foo(bar: Baz)
```

implicitly changes it to this:

```
func foo(bar bar: Baz)
```

which would make it be called like this:

```
foo(bar: Baz())
```

so one now must declare it like this:

```
func foo(_ bar: Baz)
```

in order to call it like this:

```
foo(Baz())
```

---

### Why?

The idea is that each non-self-documenting parameter must have an explicit label so that someone reading the code immediately knows that's going on. For simple methods like `setWidth(5)`, it's obvious you're setting the width to `5`, so the first parameter needs no label (`setWidth(width: 5)` would be redundant). However, for more nuanced methods like `wait(forSeconds: 5)`, it would be unclear what the `5` means without the `forSeconds:` label (`wait(5)` could easily be seen as 5 milliseconds).